# Robo-Approvers on the run?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, vandalism

How could [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/869445/revisions) edit (I rolled back immediately), get *any* approves? Please look into the robo-approvers responsible for the approval of the vandalising edit. Did any of you see such activity recently?

Comment: The editing review queue is deeply broken IMO; almost nothing short of vandalism is ever rejected, as evidenced by a brief look through the recent history, and the audits are an utter joke. For egregious cases of robo-reviewing, see my question [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15044/what-should-one-do-if-they-see-extremely-fast-reviewing).

Comment: [Relay, Ted!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/reviewing-suggested-edits-what-am-i-doing-wrong).

Comment: There should be a review queue for approved suggested edits, to review the approvals.

Comment: @This There should also be a review queue for robo-deletions by the Community user.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Then who will watch the watcher-watchers? :)

Comment: What if we kill the review related badges? Or, failing that, give two points towards a badge for rejecting an edit.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The first is a good idea (not new, but good). The second would possibly transform robo-approvers into robo-rejecters, which isn't utterly desirable either.

Comment: Ok, @Daniel. The suggestion needs more work. How about the badge needs a minimum number of both rejections and nods? Lose a point for being in a minority.

Comment: @Jyrki But what if suddenly all suggested edits are good? I still prefer just getting rid of the bloody review-badges.

Comment: LOL. Mission f%&$¤#% accomplished!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The review of the edit in question (suggested by Blind Schleiche) is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/241106).

What I believe happened in this case, however, was a *race condition*--nothing malicious.  Notice that the OP edited their post at time `23:42:21`, and the edit was approved at `23:43:41`.  I think that, just after Blind Schleiche opened the "edit" page and started editing the post, the OP edited their question.  Blind Schleiche then submitted their re-tagging suggestions.  Since Blind Schleiche submitted second, their edit would overwrite the OP's edit.

I am led to believe this because Blind Schleiche's edit essentially rolls back the OP's edit from V2 to V1 (with regards to content), but simply adds tags.

Comment: Isn't the SE system supposed to notify of new edits? I usually get a notification along the lines of "This question has already been edited"...